# Pressing CSS Styled button presents unwanted keyboard UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I have a local html resource loading in a UIWebView. One button is styled with CSS that when pressed, presents an unwanted keyboard and allows typing on the button

In my local html file

```
 <style>
    .button {
        border: 0px solid #ed1717;
        background: #e01414;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e01414), to(#e01414));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e01414, #e01414);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e01414, #e01414);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e01414, #e01414);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e01414, #e01414);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e01414 0%, #e01414 100%);
        padding: 14px 28px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
        box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;

        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: helvetica, serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

html button local resource

```
        align=center ><INPUT onclick=calculate(this.form) class=button value="Press" name=calculate_button>
```

Comment: did you try setting the `type="button"` attribute to the input element?

Comment: Thats it! no I hadnt done that, can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as correct.  Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `type="button"` attribute to the input element. This should do the trick :)